# how to use CBL_EXEC_RUN_UNIT

Tags: cobol

We are trying to call program B asynchronously from program A
when we try to call prog B from prog A using CBL_EXEC_RUN_UNIT, its giving the following error

> ```
> error code: 203, pc=43, call=1, seg=0
> 203     CALL parameter not supplied
> ```

```
Prog A:
       procedure division.
       00.
           display "INSIDE PROGRAM CALLPRG".
           string w-prog-name delimited by size
                  " " delimited size
                  w-a w-b delimited by size
                       into w-work
           initialize flags run-unit-id stack-size
           call "CBL_EXEC_RUN_UNIT" using w-work
                                     by value 11
                         by reference run-unit-id
                         by value stack-size flags
                                returning status-code
prog B:
       working-storage section.
       01 C pic 9(03).
       linkage section.
       01 A pic 9(02).
       01 B pic 9(02).
       procedure division using a b.
       00.
           display "INSIDE PROGRAM ADDTWO".
           display a.
           display b.
           add a b giving C.
           display "SUM IS ".
           display c.
           display "EXITING PROGRAM ADDTWO".
       ex.  exit.
```

We are using microfocus COBOL.

Comment: Have you tried displaying `w-work` before the call to ensure that it is set up properly?

Comment: You are not using mircofocus COBOL, you are using Micro Focus COBOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `START` statement for multi-threading.

You can find an example in your Cobol MicroFocus installation directory under `BASE\DEMO\MTHREAD\MTHREAD.CBL`.

Using the `START` statement your code will look something like this:

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.    PROGA.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   01  THREAD-HANDLE              usage thread-pointer.

   77  W77-ACCEPT-KEY PIC X.

   01  W01-NUMBERS.
   03  Num1 Pic s9(005).
   03  Num2 Pic s9(005).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   0000-MAIN SECTION.
   0000.
       MOVE 1 TO Num1.
       MOVE 2 TO Num2.

       START "PROGB"  USING W01-NUMBERS
                      IDENTIFIED BY THREAD-HANDLE.


       DISPLAY "Press any key to end me...".
       ACCEPT W77-ACCEPT-KEY.

       PERFORM 9999-FINISH-IT.
   0000-EXIT.
        EXIT.

   9999-FINISH-IT SECTION.
   9999.
       EXIT PROGRAM.
       STOP RUN.
   9999-EXIT.
        EXIT.

   END PROGRAM PROGA.

   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.    PROGB.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   77  W77-RESULT PIC S9(006).
   LINKAGE SECTION.

   01  W01-NUMBERS.
       03 Num1 Pic s9(005).
       03 Num2 Pic s9(005).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING W01-NUMBERS.
   0000-MAIN SECTION.
   0000.
       compute W77-RESULT = Num1 + Num2.
       DISPLAY "Hello from ProgB".
       Display "Result is: " W77-RESULT.

       PERFORM 9999-FINISH-IT.
   0000-EXIT.
        EXIT.

   9999-FINISH-IT SECTION.
   9999.
       EXIT PROGRAM.
       STOP RUN.
   9999-EXIT.
        EXIT.

   END PROGRAM PROGB.
```

Comment: Can the START use multiple items on the USING like the example, or just the one like here?

Comment: Hi Hudler, will this be a asynchronous call to the PRGB?

Comment: @BillWoodger: Only one argument - see 'Format 3' http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2FGUID-0E0191D8-C39A-44D1-BA4C-D67107BAF784%2FHRLHLHPDFC05.html

Comment: @user1085296: Yes, it will. I suggest you to take a look at the same above link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

The 203 message is telling you you have not established the items on the PROCEDURE DIVISION USING correctly. Either one or both of the parameters is missing from the actual call to the ADDTWO program.

I do not know if you are supplying two parameters in the "command line", and I do not know if you are supplying them correctly to be able to call the ADDTWO. ADDTWO is going to be running as thought it were a main program. How do you supply multiple parameter values to a main COBOL program in your run-environment (your operating system and Micro Focus's run-time).

I'm not sure that you should specify the length of the command line in that way. There is a different recommendation in the documentation.

Comment: Hi Bill , this is the way we are calling the PROGRAM B : call "CBL_EXEC_RUN_UNIT" using "ADDTWO 0303" by value 11 end-call. Could you say if the way we are passing teh input is wrong?

Comment: If we dont give by value 11 comment , the first caharacter of ADDTWO is taken "A" and it searches for that Program A in the dirctoey and throws an error saying the Prog A does not exist in the drive/directory.

Comment: Yes, Your CALL is wrong. 0303 is not two distinct pieces of data, but one piece of data. You could amend your LINKAGE SECTION of ADDTWO to look like @J.Hudler has shown and see what that does. If you do a simple CALL to ADDTWO as an example it would be CALL "ADDTWO" USING field-a, field-b. The USING's would match, CALL to PROCEDURE DIVISION.

Comment: My point is not that you don't need something sitting there to do the job, but that a literal is probably not the best way to do it. The Micro Focus example shows a PIC 9(4) COMP-5 field. Look at your documentation. If a numeric literal valid on a CALL is stored in that size of field, you might be OK with it, Else change it.